# C code, pointers and their content. Exam question

Tags: c, pointers

I have this code from an old exam.

The first print generates 5a9b1740.

And the question is what does the second print generate.

- x: unknown since we do not know what *k holds.
- y: 35.
- z: ffff ffff. WHY?
- p: 5c9b1748. WHY?

---

```
{
    int x = 4; 
    int y = 15; 
    int *k = &x; 
    int z;
    int *p;

    *k = *k * (*k + 1);
    y = x + y;
    k = &z;

    int a[] = {7,9,3,8};
    p = a;
    printf("%x\n",(unsigned int)p);
    x = *k + 1;
    p = p + 2;
    z = *p - 4;
    printf("%d %d %x %x\n",x,y,z,(unsigned int)p);
}
```

Edit: Sorry for causing confusion, the first print is 5a9b1740 and second 5c9b1748. Not 5a9b1740,5c961748. Question is edited on that regard.

Comment: p: 5c961748
This is the address in which the array a[] is placed in the memory stack.

Simply calling "a" refers to the address of a, and it is equivalent to "&a[0]", so it's the address of the first element in the array.

Comment: In the second `printf` call. the hex value `ffffffff` printed for `z` depends on an unstated assumption that `unsigned int` is exactly 32 bits wide. `unsigned int` is known to be at least 31 bits wide due to the hex value `5c961740` printed earlier. The hex value `5c961748` printed for `(unsigned int)p` depends on another unstated assumption that `sizeof(int)` is 4.

Comment: 5a9b1740 then 5c961748. This is clearly wrong, you are testing this the wrong way or writing the wrong numbers in the question.

Comment: Please be careful with editing questions after you got answers. And even after the edit, the value you show is not plausible.

Comment: 5c961740 was wrong, the 6 is suppose to be a b. 5c9b1740 is the correct value, i edited it :)

Comment: And the value you now show is still wrong, but pleas do NOT edit it to fix, it would invalidate existing answers, at least answers which match the question as asked. It is called a "moving target question" and not appreciated here.  It is not fair to change a question so that it does not match a noticably older answer anymore and then matches a younger answer.

Comment: Several edits on your question and the values are still as implausible as to begin with. 5c9b1748-5a9b1740=2000008 and  5c961748-5a9b1740=1FB 0008. Neither can be explained with the shown code. But please do NOT edit questions relevantly after having answers.

Comment: This question assumes the compiler lays out variables sequentially. That need not be true, it might notice that some variable isn't used (or it's value at the use site can be deduced), so it is redundant and simply left out. Or for some reason the compiler lays out the variables in some other order. It's entitled to do so, the standard doesn't specify such (to allow the above eliding variables, for example).

Comment: Yunnosch, You are welcome to compile it if you like.

Comment: @vonbrand I do not agree. This question does not require assumptions on layout. The address value should be calculatable from first print. OP simply failed to correctly copy two numbers.

Comment: Compiling is not as easy as you seem to think, given that you did not provide a [mre].

Comment: Copy past it to an online compiler. Add int main()

Comment: Thanks no. You [edit] your question please to turn the shown code fragment into a [mre]. Make sure that the code compiles without warnings, which it will not if you only add `int main()`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks to explain blatantly undefined behaviour.

Comment: @BenimSvensson : Concerning about the memory addresses `5a9b1740` & `5c9b1748`; are they the actual outcome of your system 'run' or just the example solutions given with the assignment?

Comment: @vonbrand Please elaborate which undefined behaviour you are referring to. Doing that with good explanation and reasoning would be an answer I'd be happy to upvote.

Comment: @ssd 5a9b1740 is given as the first print. Unknown, 35, ffff ffff, 5c9b1748 is the answer to the question.

Comment: @BenimSvensson : So, my suspicion is pertinent. That addresses are given with the assigment text; they are not actual outcome of your program run. Maybe, there is a typo then?

Comment: @ssd Yes, but i get the same thing when i compile it. Start adress change but always incremented by 8 for the second print.

Comment: @BenimSvensson : `Second printed address = First printed address + 2 * sizeof(int)` is OK then; since, on a 32 bits oper. sys., `2 * sizeof(int)` makes `8` bytes.

Comment: @ssd makes sens, thanks for the explanation :)

Answer (score 2):

p.s. no 3:
It comes out that, the addresses given in the question are **not** the actual outcome of a *program execution* but example values given with the assignment text. So, there is a possible typo: either both addresses would start with `5c9b...` or both w/ `5a9b...`.

p.s. no 2:
Please refer to the comments as well. Just checking the last 2 ~ 4 digits of the addresses, I overlooked the weird address gap b/w the 1st & 2nd results of the `print` lines.

Let's go line by line:

- Line 1:

```
int x = 4; // x is defined and set to value 4
```

- Line 2:

```
int y = 15; // y is defined and set to value 15
```

- Line 3:

```
int *k = &x; // pointer k is set to point x
```

- Line 4:

```
int z; // z is defined but uninitialized
```

- Line 5:

```
int *p; // pointer p is defined but uninitialized
```

- Line 7:

```
*k = *k * (*k + 1);
// k was set to point x (above)
// so, *k = x
// and x = x * (x + 1) => x = 4 * 5 = 20
```

- Line 8:

```
y = x + y
// y = 20 + 15 = 35
```

- Line 9:

```
k = &z;
// k is set to point z (but z is still uninitialized)
```

- Line 11:

```
int a[] = {7, 9, 3, 8};
// array 'a' is defined
```

- Line 12:

```
p = a;
// p is set to point the first int element of array 'a'
```

- Line 13:

```
printf("%x\n", (unsigned int)p);
// printing the memory address of p
// same as printing the memory address of array 'a'
```

- Line 14:

```
x = *k + 1; 
// k was set to point z
// but z is still uninitialized
// so, x = z + 1 is unpredictable so far
// x is, whatever the value z plus 1
```

- Line 15:

```
p = p + 2; 
// p was set to point first integer element of array 'a'
// so, after p = p + 2, p = address of 'a' + 2 * sizeof(int)
// since sizeof(int) = 4 bytes, p is now address(a) + 8
// p is now pointing to the third element of array 'a'
// that is, p is pointing to '3'; *p = 3
```

- Line 16:

```
z = *p - 4; 
// p was set to point third element of array 'a'
// *p was '3'
// so, z = *p - 4 means z = 3 - 4 = -1
```

- Line 17:

```
printf("%d %d %x %x\n", x, y, z, (unsigned int)p);
// x is, what ever the value of z plus 1
// y is 35
// z is -1; its hex representation if ffff ffff
// p is address of array a plus 2; p = &a[0] + 2
// that is; p is now, address of array 'a' + 2 * sizeof(int)
```

p.s. Yes, I had nothing else to do today.

Comment: Be careful with the implausible addresses. OP is creating a moving target question.

Comment: You are aware that your pointer explanation as is does not match the address values stated in the question, aren't you? Assuming that OP does not keep changing the values, ( 5c9b1748 - 5a9b1740 ) is 2000008, not 8.

Comment: @Yunnosch : Address of array `a` depends on the system I'm / you're / he's using. But for sure, the address printed in the second `print` line is `2 * sizeof(int)` bytes forward than the address printed in the first `print` line. Am I wrong?

Comment: Youh should be right, but comparing to the values reported by OP in  the question there is a conflict. I bet the problem is errors in OPs copy pasting, but without further details your explanation does not match waht OP is asking about. OP has already tried to match the question to your answer, but did not succeed.

Comment: Oppps, you're right. I just checked the last 2 ~ 4 digits of the memory address. There is sth really weird then.

Comment: That is a widely spread habit (see comments on my answer). I recommed to adapt your explanation to this conflict. Maybe just state your assumption. Try to provide additional insight if possible. Otherwise the votes on our answers will reflect how closely voters actually read questions.... ;-)

Answer (score 2):

> `x`: unknown since we do not know what `*k` holds.

Technically, the value of `*k` when `x = *k + 1;` was executed is **indeterminate** since it points to `z` and `z` was uninitialized at that time.  This means the value is either **unspecified** (i.e. it can have any value) or a **trap representation** (i.e. it doesn't represent a valid value and can trigger a fault if read).  If the value happens to be a trap representation then reading invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

In some cases reading an uninitialized variable can still be undefined even if it is not a trap representation, however that is not the case here because `z` had its address taken.

> y: 35.

At this point:

```
*k = *k * (*k + 1);
y = x + y;
```

`k` points to `x` and 4 has the value 4, so the first line is the same as `x = 4 * (4 + 1)`.  This sets `x` to 20, then adding that to the current value of `y` (15) gives 35.

> z: ffff ffff. WHY?
>
> p: 5c9b1748. WHY?

Looking at these lines:

```
p = a;
p = p + 2;
z = *p - 4;
```

This first points `p` to the first element of `a`, and that pointer has value 5a9b1740 as in the first `printf`. The next line then points it to 2 elements after that one.  Assuming an `int` is 4 bytes on your system, that means the raw value of the pointer `p` increased 2 * 4 = 8.  So the value of `p` is now 5a9b1740 + 8 = 5a9b1748.

With `p` now pointing to the third element of `a` which has the value 3, the following line sets `z` to -1.  This value is then printed with the `%x` format specifier which interprets the value as an `unsigned int` and prints it in hex.  Assuming two's complement representation of negative numbers an (again) a 4 byte `int`, this value has the representation `ffffffff`.  When read as an `unsigned int` is is this that is printed.

Answer (score 1):

```
{
    int x = 4; 
    int y = 15; 
    int *k = &x; 
    int z;
    int *p;

    *k = *k * (*k + 1); /* x = x * (x+1) i.e. 20 */
    y = x + y; /* y = 20 + 15 i.e. 35 */
    k = &z; /* fine, though the content is not initialised */

    int a[] = {7,9,3,8};
    p = a;
    printf("%x\n",(unsigned int)p);
    x = *k + 1; /* x = z +1 which is unknown because content of z still not initialised */
    p = p + 2; /* pointing to 3 now */
    z = *p - 4; /* z= 3 - 4 ; i.e. -1 */
    printf("%d %d %x %x\n",x,y,z,(unsigned int)p);
}
```

The result prints a signed integer (`z`) as unsigned, which in this case results in the representation of -1 in the twos-complement hex representation, but shown as unsigned, i.e. "ffff ffff" in 32bit.
I initially was confused by `z` not being intialised, but it turns out to be irrelevant.
It seems to me that the value of p would not really have been predictable.
Judging from the first print being "5a9b1740", the value should be bigger by the size of two ints, i.e. "5a9b1748" on most systems. But that does not match the output you show (before or after your edit to the question; please note 5c9b1748-5a9b1740=2000008 and 5c961748-5a9b1740=1FB 0008. Neither can be explained with the shown code. For some reason people fail to see the large difference and focus only on the few least significant nibbles...)
If those two values come from different runs of the program, then it could explain the difference with intentional randomisation. (Thanks to Gerhardh for making me look for an explanation.)

Comment: The value of `p` is simply derived from output of first `printf`. As I understand the question, that value is given and in second `printf` it is just increased by `2*sizeof int`.

Comment: @Gerhardh I thought so too. Hard to explain owever the difference (5c961748 - 5a9b1740) with the size of two ints. Did I miss something?

Comment: Ups, you are right. I missed 2 digits and only noticed the difference of 8 in the lower half.

Comment: Still a good input, I think I have used it to improve my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

This is blatantly undefined behavior. The compiler is allowed to lay out variables in any order it likes, even leave variables without backing store (it  just keeps the value in a register, sees it isn't ever used, or can deduce it's value each time it is used and doesn't require storing it, ever. You *can not* legally point outside the referenced object by adding to the pointer. For a rather dumb compiler (or no optimization whatsoever) the above might be right. Or it might not.

For examples of the above, compile some program with e.g. `gcc -O2 -g` and debug it. When single-stepping the debugger will often jump around seemingly at random in the source, skip some statements altogether, tell you some variables have been optimized out, and others.

Comment: There is no pointing outside of the bounds of an object here.